# How to integrate sauce-connect-launcher on webdriver.io wdio.conf.js file

Tags: testing, saucelabs, webdriver-io

I read this http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/cloudservices.html, but not find how launch the tunnel inside the wdio.conf.js and how integrate.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow can help you, but we won't do the work for you.

Comment: i answered my question, i try help the developers have the same problem.

Comment: Hey allel, StackOverflow is a Q&A site, it is thus meant to ask a question and have the community help with finding a solution. It is allowed to answer your own question if you happen to find the answer somewhere else. however StackOverflow is not a place to post tutorials, for that you can use your own site or even wiki-how.

Comment: @SZenC It is perfectly fine for someone to share their knowledge in a Q&A format on SO. In fact, when you post a question *SO itself prompts you to post an answer right away*. **However**, the rules regarding the quality of the question and the answer are not suspended for users who post self-answered questions, and unfortunately, this is where many self-answerers fail. The question they post should be fleshed out to the same extent as any other question posted on SO. The fact that they know the answer already does not excuse them from including code, what they tried, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Now webdriver.io latest version have documentation to integrate the cloud testing services.

See to more:

http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/cloudservices.html

---

Fomerly to integrate the sauce-connect-launcher you need the wdio.conf.js file, and inside the file configure the sauce-connect-launcher to launch the tunnel, example wdio.conf.js file:

```
var sauceConnectLauncher = require('sauce-connect-launcher');
global.sauceConnectProcess = null;

exports.config = {

//
// ==================
// Specify Test Files
// ==================
// Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
// from which `wdio` was called. Notice that, if you are calling `wdio` from an
// NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) then the current working
// directory is where your package.json resides, so `wdio` will be called from there.
//

user: 'the_pianist2',
key: '27dde83a-1cf7-450d-8c88-857c4d3cde43',    
specs: [
    //command line
    //'spec/**/*.js' wdio wdio.conf.js
    //grunt
    './www-test/e2e/spec/*.js'
],
// Patterns to exclude.
exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
],
//
// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilties at the same
// time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
// sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude option in
// order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
//
// If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
// Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
// https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator
//
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome'
},
{
    browserName: 'firefox'
}
],
//
// ===================
// Test Configurations
// ===================
// Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
//
// Level of logging verbosity.
//logLevel: 'result',
//
// Enables colors for log output.
coloredLogs: true,
//
// Saves a screenshot to a given path if a command fails.
screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
//
// Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your url parameter starts
// with "/", the base url gets prepended.
//desarrollo
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
//produccion
//baseUrl: 'http://www.example.com',
//
// Default timeout for all waitForXXX commands.
waitforTimeout: 20000,
//
// Initialize the browser instance with a WebdriverIO plugin. The object should have the
// plugin name as key and the desired plugin options as property. Make sure you have
// the plugin installed before running any tests. The following plugins are currently
// available:
// WebdriverCSS: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss
// WebdriverRTC: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverrtc
// Browserevent: https://github.com/webdriverio/browserevent
// plugins: {
//     webdrivercss: {
//         screenshotRoot: 'my-shots',
//         failedComparisonsRoot: 'diffs',
//         misMatchTolerance: 0.05,
//         screenWidth: [320,480,640,1024]
//     },
//     webdriverrtc: {},
//     browserevent: {}
// },
//
// Framework you want to run your specs with.
// The following are supported: mocha, jasmine and cucumber
// see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/frameworks.html
//
// Make sure you have the node package for the specific framework installed before running
// any tests. If not please install the following package:
// Mocha: `$ npm install mocha`
// Jasmine: `$ npm install jasmine`
// Cucumber: `$ npm install cucumber`
framework: 'jasmine',
//
// Test reporter for stdout.
// The following are supported: dot (default), spec and xunit
// see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/reporters.html
reporter: 'spec',
reporterOptions: {
    //
    // If you are using the "xunit" reporter you should define the directory where
    // WebdriverIO should save all unit reports.
    outputDir: './'
},
//
// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    //
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000,
    //
    // The Jasmine framework allows it to intercept each assertion in order to log the state of the application
    // or website depending on the result. For example it is pretty handy to take a screenshot everytime
    // an assertion fails.
    expectationResultHandler: function(passed, assertion) {

    }
},

//
// =====
// Hooks
// =====
// Run functions before or after the test. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO
// will wait until that promise got resolved to continue.
//
// Gets executed before all workers get launched.
onPrepare: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sauceConnectLauncher({
          username: 'the_pianist2',
          accessKey: '27dde83a-1cf7-450d-8c88-857c4d3cde43',
        }, function (err, sauceConnectProcess) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log('conexion realizada');
            global.sauceConnectProcess = sauceConnectProcess
            resolve();
        });
    });


},
//
// Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you will have access to all global
// variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
before: function() {
    // do something
},
//
// Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
// the test.
after: function(failures, pid) {
    // do something
},
//
// Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. It is not
// possible to defer the end of the process using a promise.
onComplete: function() {
    console.log('Test completado');
      global.sauceConnectProcess.close(function () {
        console.log("Closed Sauce Connect process");
        return true;
      });        
}};
```

In the hook 'onPrepare' the script to connect tunnel is launch and the inside Promise is very important because wait the callback of connection and run the next steps after finish onPrepare functions:

https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1062

After that the test is launching on the server saucelabs.